# R Shiny: Check a Regular expression in textInput on UI

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Is this possible when a user input something on `textInput` to against a regular expression and give a warning.

Such that the textInput area expects: `[1-5]GH[0-9]`

But when the input is: `5UK8`
The warning should be: `Check your input`

I think this can be done using JS inside UI, but is there any Shiny trick? Or if you can help with a java script.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("id", "Enter your ID",),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({ input$id })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe with `shinyFeedback` ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),

  textInput("id", "Enter your ID",),

  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$id, {
    feedbackWarning(
      "id",
      condition = !grepl("[1-5]GH[0-9]", input$id)
    )
  })

  output$value <- renderText({ input$id })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Meanwhile the argument 'condition' has been replaced by 'show'.